# why is the for loop not running?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I'm supposed to create a function that will continue to double the first argument until it is greater than or equal to the 2nd argument. Every time it doubles, I add 20 to a counter.

However, for whatever reason, it doesn't seem to be adding 20 to the counter as it always returns 0 and does not print the console.log I included for each loop, which makes me think it's not running the loop.

Why isn't it running the loop and what am I doing wrong?

```js
function bacteriaTime(currentNum, targetNum) {
  let counter = 0
  for (let i = currentNum; i >= targetNum; i *= 2) {
    counter += 20;
    console.log('bacteria count is ' + i + ' and ' + counter + ' have passed.')
  }
  return counter;
  console.log(counter);
}
```

Comment: How are you calling it? Anything after `return counter` will be ignored because... you've returned.

Comment: `currentNum` starts as less than `targetNum` correct? The condition is backwards then. You want to check for it being *less than* `targetNum`.

Comment: What is `currentNum` and `targetNum`?

Comment: I'd recommend (strongly) that you work through it with a pencil and paper using small numbers as your inputs. "Play computer" and figure out what's actually happening by processing every step. For example, `currentNum` as 0, `targetNum` as, say, 3.

Comment: First. The console.log never print the result because the return is before. So the function end in the return. Second, you need to check what value has targetNum because the condition isn't true.

Comment: I left out the part that returns a message if currentNum is greater than targetNum as I know that part of the code works.

Comment: Good to know about where to stick the return part. the explanations I found about what it does and how to use it are sort of vague.

Comment: @TabbieC https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return Nothing particularly vague there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you've mixed up your comparison. In your for loop you had `i >= targetNum` which with your inputs would almost always be `false`. Simply switch the operator to `<=` as below and you should be good. This will mean `i` is less than `targetNum`.

```
function bacteriaTime (currentNum,targetNum){
    let counter = 0
    for (let i = currentNum; i <= targetNum; i *= 2){
        counter += 20;
        console.log ('bacteria count is ' + i + ' and ' + counter+ ' have passed.')
        }
    console.log(counter);
    return counter;
}
```

Hope that works. It was probably just a simple mix up.

Comment: `console.log` is still after the return.

Comment: -_-; yup it was the >= vs <=.  Still getting used to that.  Thanks.

Comment: @TabbieC No problem we have all been there. I will note as Intervalia you will need to move the second console.log to before the return otherwise it won't print. I have updated my response for that. Mark this as the answer so that everyone knows this is solved. :)

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna check if your condition wasn't already met, and therefore, the code has returned. Also your condition is backwards. It should be: `for (let i = currentNum; i <= targetNum; i *= 2) {`